# Export vector layer with labels to Google Earth as kmz

Tags: qgis, labeling, google-earth

I have a vector file with contours which i am interested to export it as kmz to google earth **with labels** similar to the ones QGIS labeling function produces. However I read that Google earth does not offer such function and renaming each contour to the corresponding elevation through NameField is not enough for this case i work on. Is there any work around to this issue?

"*This is a known limit. **Google Earth only displays labels for point features (placemarks).** To display labels for line or polygon features in Google Earth, midpoints or centroids for those feature classes must be created as a point layer in ArcMap and imported as a separate layer to Google Earth.*"

Reference: 
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012154

Comment: Depending on the number of contour lines you have, you could export single heights separately to `kml` and then put them all together in Google Earth into a `kmz`, giving each height a different colour.

Comment: @Erik am afraid that the range of the contours vries between 0 to 1000m with a step of 10 meters. However i am not interested into coloring the contours but labeling them

Comment: From a cartographic point of view it is nonsense to represent the range from 0 to 1000 m using 10m steps. That said, do you have a concept on how ofter you want to repeat the labels?

Comment: @ERIK due to the fact the slopes are very mild it make sense to this spesific project i work on. When you say how often i assume you mean on the same contour, if that is the case every 500 meters along the length of the contour it is quite good for what i want, otherwhise if the contour is less than 500 meters then just a signle time